Why isn't my image showing in my react project?
I just started learning React and I'm trying to build a static HTML page. Everything works fine except the React logo image which has refused to show.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client"

const page = (
  <div>
    <img src="first-project/public/logo512.png" width="40px"/>
    <h1>Fun facts about React</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>Was released in 2013</li>
      <li>Was originally created by Jordan Walke</li>
      <li>Has well over 100k stars on Github</li>
      <li>Is maintained by facebook</li>
      <li>Powers thousands of enterprise apps, including mobile apps</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
)

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
root.render(page)

I copied the image from my public folder and for some reason it does not display properly on the web browser.
The image below shows how the image appears on the webpage

The image below shows my IDE:


Try this --> src='/public/logo512.png'
Explantion
It seems you are in the src folder --> index.js file and try to access a file in public folder. It means you have to go a folder back to access that folder since public and src folder hold a common root.
1. If the file you're currently working on and the file you're going to access in the same folder you can start it like this './'
2. If the folder of the file you are currently working on and the folder of the file you're going to access have a common root you can access it like this '/'

Simply use
<img src="logo512.png" width="40px"/>

React by default points assets from public folder.

Try use /public/logo512.png as image url.
<img src="/public/logo512.png" width="40px"/>

This should be correct path.
